# System.Threading.Timer not firing, global.aspx

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, global-asax

I am a newbie, but I am unable to get this code working.  FileSweeper is supposed to start a timmer that triggers fileCopy on a web server. fileSweeoer is triggered by global.asax. FileCopy then will copy the file.  However the FC.copy never fires. Any help/explanation would be helpful!

Would it make any difference if this was a class running on a web server?

My code is from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System
Imports System.Threading

Public Class fileSweeper

Dim stateTimer As Timer

<MTAThread()> _
Sub Main()
    Dim FC As New fileCopy
    Dim tcb As TimerCallback = AddressOf FC.Copy

    stateTimer = New Timer(tcb, "", 20000, 200000)
    GC.KeepAlive(stateTimer)
End Sub
```

End Class

Global.asax:

```
<%@ Application Language="VB" %>

<script runat="server">

Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Sub Application_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs on application shutdown
End Sub

Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
End Sub

Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs when a new session is started
    Dim FS As New fileSweeper
    FS.Main()
End Sub

Sub Session_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs when a session ends. 
    ' Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
    ' is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
    ' or SQLServer, the event is not raised.
End Sub

</script>
```

Comment: Where do you enable the timer?

Comment: @Micheal Eakins what do you mean, can you clarify?  THX

Comment: Is this a Web Site? If so, do you have a Web Form? Something has to kick off the Session_Start event. I've tested your code, and if the Session_Start event fires, then your code does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably going to get unexpected results here because you are likely going to get multiple sessions on a web server.  You might want to consider creating a console app and using windows task scheduler.